# How to define += extension functions on CGSize

Tags: ios, swift

I want to add two CGSize functions using `+`. I can do that simply with

```
extension CGSize{
    static func +(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> CGSize{
        CGSize(width: lhs.width + rhs.width, height: lhs.height + rhs.height)
    }
}
```

the problem is that it allows me to do  `let result = size1 + size2` **but** I cannot do  `size1 += size2`. How do I define such that `+=` works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must also define the `+=` operator. As an assignment operator, its left-hand-side parameter should be `inout` and it should return `Void`.

```
extension CGSize {
    static func += (lhs: inout Self, rhs: Self) {
        lhs.width += rhs.width
        lhs.height += rhs.height
    }
}
```

Or, taking advantage of your existing definition of `+`:

```
extension CGSize {
    static func += (lhs: inout Self, rhs: Self) {
        lhs = lhs + rhs
    }
}
```